# repeated mysql fetch results in high resources usage on php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, web

In my Php page i used repeated checks for new updates/insert using Ajax that results in high resource usage.One code i used for notification as follows.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Notification WHERE user_id='$_GET[user_id]'";
  $count=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
  $cnt=mysqli_query($conn, $count);                                   
  $ct=mysqli_num_rows($cnt);
```

Similar mysql fetch used in chatting page results in server error(more than 50 users sending messages and inserting data to db so lots of rows, moreover app on shared hosting).
How can i avoid regular check and get data when the new data inserted or updated in db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say how much data is in your table. There are several possible reasons for the problem

1) Lots of records returned from this query - quite possible for active users
2) You don't have an index on the user_id column, which means expensive queries

You probably need to ask only for data since the last time you asked, which will be more efficient

Comment: For chat more than 50 users chatting and inserting data. so i regular checks the db for new message. more over the app on shared hosting server.